# ”volatile“ in the ”HashMap“ about ”modCount“

Tags: java, hashmap

Why  the `HashMap` don't use `volatile` to modify `modCount` to make sure that a thread can immediately know the change of the `Map` when another thread change it?

Snippet below:

```
/**
 * The number of times this HashMap has been structurally modified
 * Structural modifications are those that change the number of mappings 
in
 * the HashMap or otherwise modify its internal structure (e.g.,
 * rehash).  This field is used to make iterators on Collection-views of
 * the HashMap fail-fast.  (See ConcurrentModificationException).
 */
transient int modCount;
```

Comment: Because HashMap is specifically designed not to be thread-safe.  You can use Hashtable or use Collections.synchronizedMap to make it thread-safe if you need.  But if you don’t need thread safety, it’s pointless overhead.

Comment: Don't be fooled by the "Concurrent" in "ConcurrentModificationException" - concurrent here means "modifying the collection concurrent with iterating over it". It doesn't mean concurrency as in multi-threading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only benefit of declaring `modCount` to be `volatile` would be to make the "fail fast" detection of concurrent modifications faster ... in some cases:

- For a `HashMap` that is thread confined (i.e. used by only one thread) there is no functional benefit.  The thread is guaranteed to see the updates that it makes to `modCount`.
- For a `HashMap` that is not thread confined but (properly) synchronized some other way, the synchronization should ensure that `modCount` is not stale when viewed from another thread than the one that updated it.  Again, no functional benefit.
- For a `HashMap` that is not thread confined and not properly synchronized, yoou are doing it wrong, and you have much bigger problems<sup>1</sup> to worry about than "fail fast" detection of concurrent modifications not being immediate.  So the benefit is .... marginal.

And the counterpoint to the above is that declaring `modCount` to be `volatile` *will* incur a performance penalty (in the form of memory barriers and extra memory reads and writes)  for all `HashMap` operations that read or write that field.  (And that is most of them.)

In summary: zero or minimal benefit versus performance overheads that could be significant in some use-cases.

---

<sup>1 - For example, [heisenbug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) `HashMap` corruptions.</sup>